# Get data from exactly 30 days ago only in SQL (Big Query)

Tags: google-bigquery

In BigQuery I am trying to extract data from an exact date, 30 days ago, so that every day when I pull/refresh the data, it is always 30 days ago - no more, no less, however using the following it pulls in two dates:

```
SELECT FORMAT_DATE("%Y-%m-%d",createddatetime1) as dated, brand, orderid
FROM TABLE

AND createddatetime1 between TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 29 DAY)
```

I have tried different tactics, such as convert and cast, but I cant seem to pull data for one day only. createddatetime1 is formatted as "2022-08-02 23:53:57 UTC"

Example current output, you'll see two dates in there:

```
Row createddatetime1    brand   orderid
1   2022-08-02 23:53:57 UTC ABC 1
2   2022-08-02 14:11:05 UTC ABC 2
3   2022-08-02 13:31:52 UTC ABC 3
4   2022-08-02 20:14:16 UTC ABC 4
5   2022-08-02 23:18:28 UTC ABC 5
6   2022-08-02 17:27:06 UTC ABC 6
7   2022-08-03 01:44:12 UTC ABC 7
8   2022-08-03 09:57:19 UTC ABC 8
9   2022-08-02 12:32:23 UTC ABC 9
10  2022-08-02 18:52:33 UTC ABC 10
```

Expected output:

```
Row createddatetime1    brand   orderid
1   02/08/2022  ABC 1
2   02/08/2022  ABC 2
3   02/08/2022  ABC 3
4   02/08/2022  ABC 4
5   02/08/2022  ABC 5
6   02/08/2022  ABC 6
7   02/08/2022  ABC 7
8   02/08/2022  ABC 8
9   02/08/2022  ABC 9
10  02/08/2022  ABC 10
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data for both expected and actual output?

Comment: Added that in above, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're getting data for both dates as BETWEEN has both boundaries inclusive i.e. Both the start and end values are included. You need to extract the date from the timestamp column and use equality to filter the required rows.

This should work

```
where DATE(createddatetime1) = DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT 
Date(createddatetime1) as date, brand, orderid
FROM TABLE
where DATE(createddatetime1) = current_date()-30
```